# ZXing Library: Errors in iOS: private field 'cached_y_' is not used

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, zxing

I am currently trying to use the ZXing Library for an iOS Project. However I can't even get the sample Projects to work.

The ScanTest Project, as well as the ones that I created myself throw the following error in the BinaryBitmap.cpp file.

```
In file included from /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Tim/Downloads/zxing-2.1/iphone/ZXingWidget/../../cpp/core/src/zxing/BinaryBitmap.cpp:20:
../../cpp/core/src/zxing/BinaryBitmap.h:33:7: error: private field 'cached_y_' is not used [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]
            int cached_y_;
                ^
1 error generated.
```

I searched on Google and Stackoverflow, but have not found a solution for the problem.

I have tried it with both the current stable release of XCode and the beta.

I don't know if anybody else has got this problem too, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What this means is that that particular data member is never used (surprisingly enough). This isn't an error in itself, you would normally just get a warning (because you probably did mean to use it). The option `-Werror` means turn warnings into errors. I don't know how you are trying to compile the examples, but maybe you need to change the compiler options.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks :) removing the two compiler flags solved the problem. If you post it as an answer, I'll choose it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is clang, right? You can read about the relevant compiler options [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages).
The error message is telling you which compiler flags are relevant.

`-Wunused-private-field` means you get warnings about private member fields of classes (or structs, ...) that are not used anywhere. The warning is because you probably did mean to use them. This would not normally stop the compilation, but...

`-Werror` turns warnings into errors. A lot of people use this option to force themselves to write very clean code. Taking this one out should be enough.