# Error : Unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'i386'

Tags: ios, zxing, gcc-4.2

I have downloaded **zxing sdk**.
in that their a sample code called scantest i am trying to run that sample code in xcode 4.6.2
but it give me error.

**"Unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'i386'"**

i am trying i am not getting solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding correct compiler in build Setting.

You add (Apple LLVM 4.2 Compiler)Goto Build Setting And select this Compiler...

try this one...

Comment: can u give me proper path where to set it

Comment: go to Project Setting and then you see BuildSetting go to buildsetting.then see build option then select compiler C C++ objcetive C compiler..

Comment: above error is solve but new error is coming .../cpp/core/src/zxing/BinaryBitmap.h:33:7: Private field 'cached_y_' is not used

Comment: if your error is solved accept this answer..what is cached_y_

Comment: for the another error generated you could try this one -Werror turns warnings into errors. A lot of people use this option to force themselves to write very clean code. Taking this one out should be enough.

Comment: i got the answer in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447230/zxing-library-errors-in-ios-private-field-cached-y-is-not-used)